# Android things error: unable to merge dex

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, android-things

i am doing project on motion sensor camera using android things and firebase and notification through mobile

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':mobile:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

i add "multidexenabled true" but no solution

this is App level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "za.co.riggaroo.motioncamera"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true //Added this
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
ext {
    archVersion = '1.1.0'
    playServices = "11.8.0"
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${playServices}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${playServices}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:${playServices}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${playServices}"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.7-devpreview'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:${archVersion}"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:${archVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:${archVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: clean project and rebuild ?

Comment: i did..the same error showing

Comment: I see you're including a lot of libraries, which may be giving a multi-dex problem. Do you need all of these libs? Cleaning up dependencies may resolve your issue.

Comment: it shows versions conflict error..so i added specific libraries